# Rails + JQuery: Getting to a sibling div from script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

I have a rails partial that renders this html:

```
<div class="content"></div>
<script>
    // load the content here and get the adjacent div and populate it.
</script>
```

This partial template gets embedded in the main document by the server and also several times as response to AJAX requests. So the page has several instances of this partial.

Whenever my script executes I want only the div adjacent to the script to be affected.

So I am hoping if I could get to the script, I can get to the div. I use jQuery as well and I also use several async scripts (this prevents me from using the last executed script)

I could get to the adjacent div through `document.currentScript` , the problem is some browsers don't support it.

Then, is the only way to do is to create some sort of a UUID ID for the div and access it by Id from the DOM?

I really wished div supported onload, but sadly not.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the element immediately after the `<script>` (`document.write`) and find the `.content` relative to it.

```
(function(){
  var id = 'id' + (new Date().getTime());

  document.write('<div id="'+id+'"></div>');

  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  var content = elem.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling;

  content.innerHTML = 'NEW CONTENT';
})();
```

[Example jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lihowuxeci/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If each partial belongs to an ActiveRecord model, use [dom_id](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RecordIdentifier.html#method-i-dom_id) function available in Rails - in the div and in the corresponding script.

Use jQuery [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

```
<div id="div_id" class="content"></div>
<script>
    # on document load
    $('#div_id').replaceWith(new_content);
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is it will then load the new content on some other div since there are several instances of this partial in the page, potentially multiple divs with the same id.